# Problems with adding to an ArrayList while keeping a sorted order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

So I'm having trouble with this homework assignment. Essentially we have to create class SortedArrayList which extends java.util.ArrayList, and override the default add methods of ArrayList so that we can maintain a sorted list of integers that go from lowest to highest.

Here is the code that my professor gave the class to test our methods:

```
package Asg3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import myUtil.SortedArrayList;

public class Asg3 {



    public static void testInteger() {
        SortedArrayList<Integer> sorted= new SortedArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            sorted.add((int)(Math.random()*1000));
        }
        int bad=0;
        for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            try {
                sorted.add((int)(Math.random()*1000)%sorted.size(),(int)(Math.random()*1000));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.print(".");
                bad++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nsize: "+sorted.size()+"  bad insertions: "+bad);
        System.out.println(sorted.toString());
    }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        testInteger();



    }

}
```

Here is what I have so far to override the add methods so that they will maintain a sorted arraylist.

```
package myUtil;

public class SortedArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>>extends java.util.ArrayList<T>
{
    public SortedArrayList()
    {

    }

    public SortedArrayList(int capacity)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T item)
    {
        int index=this.size()-1;

    //checks to see if item is greater than or equivalent to the last element in the list   
    if(item.compareTo(this.get(index))>=0||this.get(index)==null)
    {
        //creates a new element at the end of the list and sets the value of item to it
        this.set(index+1,item);

    }
    return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void add(int i, T item)
    {
        //check to see if item is greater than the previous element, and less than the next element
        if(item.compareTo(this.get(i-1))<0 && item.compareTo(this.get(i+1))>0)
        this.set(i, item);  
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error saying: Exception in thread "main" ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

at myUtil.SortedArrayList.add(SortedArrayList.java:21)

line 21 of SortedArrayList is the if statement in the boolean add method.

Sorry for posting if this seems like a dumb question, but my professor hasn't showed up during his posted office hours for the past 2 days, so I just don't really have anywhere else to go for help. As always thank you all for your responses in advance.

Comment: Well, what happens when your list is initially empty, and then you add an element?

Comment: Update your code and add complete classes with names so that i copy paste exactly same code on my IDE to run and fix the issue for you.

Comment: @Waqas Ahmed, ok just copy and pasted the complete code over, thanks for any solutions you can come up with.

Comment: (Side note: this is a _very_ icky assignment, because it's telling you deliberately to break the `List` contract.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman what do you mean by breaking the List Contract? I'm just curious is all.

Comment: @skulltula `List.add(E)` is specified to always add the element to the end of the list.  `List.add(int, E)` is specified to always add the element to the specified index.  Adding it to a different place means that you have something that's pretending to be a `List` and lying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from when the list is initially empty so index = -1. In which case one possible solution is to surround the whole thing in an if statement:

```
if (this.size()!=0)
{
    ...    //Your code goes here
}
else this.set(0, item);
```

EDIT:

So it turns out, there are more problems than that. Here is my final code; hopefully you can read through it and understand what I've changed. (Among other things, I've added tests for special cases.)

This should show something like this:

```
size: 21  bad insertions: 19    //This should always add up to 40, because an add() method is called 40 times in total by testInteger()
[64, 65, 155, 281, 284, 340, 363, 444, 529, 596, 600, 628, 665, 745, 782, 856, 872, 885, 891, 899, 996]
```

```
package myUtil;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SortedArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>>extends java.util.ArrayList<T>
{
    public SortedArrayList() {}

    public SortedArrayList(int capacity) {}

    @Override
    public boolean add(T item)
    {
        int index=this.size();
        //Adds item to every position until it finds one that works
        for (int i=0;i<=index;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                add(i,item);
                break;
        }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
        }   
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void add(int i, T item)
    {
        //Tests for special cases with if statements.
        //If item is inserted into the wrong place, throws IllegalArgumentException()
        if (i<=size())
        {
            if (size()==0) super.add(item);
            else if (i==size())
            {
                if(item.compareTo(this.get(i-1))>=0)
                    super.add(i, item);
                else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            else if (i==0)
            {
                if(item.compareTo(this.get(i))<=0)
                    super.add(i, item);
                else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            else
            {
                if(item.compareTo(this.get(i-1))>=0&&item.compareTo(this.get(i))<=0)
                    super.add(i, item);
                else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: return true; would have to go outside the if/else statement.

Comment: I just tried implementing your solution, and got a bit of a diffrent error code. I thought that was the issue as well... anyways now the error is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
 at myUtil.SortedArrayList.add(SortedArrayList.java:32)
 at Asg3.Asg3.testInteger(Asg3.java:25)
 at Asg3.Asg3.main(Asg3.java:57)

Comment: much appreciated for your help

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't use set(index,value) to extend the size of an ArrayList - you need to use add() for that.

Comment: but the add() method has been overridden so you can't use add().

Comment: Yea I tried just using the default add method but like Sal said, I can't because it's overridden. I also tried using Super().add but that to did not seem to work.

Comment: you mean super.add(), not super().add?

Comment: @SalvatoreElia yea sorry i mean super.add(), I'll try to give it another shot if you think that will work.

Comment: i tried using super.add(item) instead of set and it worked for me. Now the problem is that the add(int i, T item) method is not working

Comment: Yep, that worked! thanks for the help so far, but yea the the other add method is still a problem.

Comment: I fixed it - what I think your professor wants you to do is to throw an IllegalArgumentException (because he surrounded that method in try/catch (IllegalArgumentException e)

Comment: try
        {
         if(item.compareTo(this.get(i-1))<0 && item.compareTo(this.get(i+1))>0)
         super.add(i, item);  
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

Comment: that is my code, with it i got:...........
size: 3  bad insertions: 11
[797, 920, 957]

Comment: I literally was just mid way through creating a try/catch block, when I read that you did and it works. it works on my end as well! Thank you so much for the help man.

Comment: It's okay, I'm just happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you retrieve the 'previous' and 'next' element from the existing ArrayList for comparison, without checking if these elements actually exist. The special cases to consider are: the list is empty; insertion before the first element, or addition after the last element.

Once your attempted insertion passes the sorting checks, you can use `super.add(value)` and `super.add(position, value)` for the actual manipulation. As far as I can tell, there is no need to use the set() method at any point.

(Since this is homework, I am hesitant to provide (pseudo-)code without at least giving you a chance to think about the special cases yourself.)

Comment: ahhhh ok thank you, so just to clarify I have to check and see if the indexes that I'm checking even exist in the first place correct? yea hold off on giving me that pseudo code.

Comment: Exactly. And it would help if you expanded your question by explaining what the new add(value) and add(position, value) are exactly expected to do - I have a feeling that the new add(value) is supposed to do some active sorting as well (hat-tip to @louis-wasserman for bringing it up)

Comment: Yea I managed to get the program to work just by using a try/catch block which both me and @SalvatoreElia think my professor wanted me to use in the first place. I'm still gunna implement some sorting checks later on in the night as I definitely see how my code in it's current state has some problems. Anyways thank you for taking the time to help me out. Time to take a long ass break.